# NoClassDefFoundError when calling Jersey REST client

Tags: java, maven, jersey-client

I am trying to build a simple rest client using jersey, but for some reason I am getting this error.

```
Nov 12, 2020 12:27:29 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors logErrors
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: HK2 service reification failed for [org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.DataSourceProvider] with an exception:
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3215)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2435)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities$3.run(Utilities.java:1308)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities$3.run(Utilities.java:1304)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getAllConstructors(Utilities.java:1304)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.findProducerConstructor(Utilities.java:1247)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.DefaultClassAnalyzer.getConstructor(DefaultClassAnalyzer.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.JerseyClassAnalyzer.getConstructor(JerseyClassAnalyzer.java:144)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getConstructor(Utilities.java:178)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:129)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:180)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.internalReify(SystemDescriptor.java:740)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:694)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:461)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.narrow(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2288)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.access$1200(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:125)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$9.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1373)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$9.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1368)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.internal.WeakCARCacheImpl.compute(WeakCARCacheImpl.java:116)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1430)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1355)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1344)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getServiceHandles(Providers.java:354)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getCustomProviders(Providers.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.<init>(MessageBodyFactory.java:221)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1375)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:272)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:366)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:122)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2022)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:774)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getUnqualifiedService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:786)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.IterableProviderImpl.get(IterableProviderImpl.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.RequestProcessingInitializationStage.apply(RequestProcessingInitializationStage.java:97)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.RequestProcessingInitializationStage.apply(RequestProcessingInitializationStage.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages$LinkedStage.apply(Stages.java:308)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:252)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:684)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:411)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:311)
    at com.tanmay.RestClient.ClientClass.main(ClientClass.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataSource
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 62 more
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Errors were discovered while reifying SystemDescriptor(
    implementation=org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.DataSourceProvider
    contracts={javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter,javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader}
    scope=javax.inject.Singleton
    qualifiers={}
    descriptorType=CLASS
    descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
    metadata=
    rank=0
    loader=org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder$2@87a85e1
    proxiable=null
    proxyForSameScope=null
    analysisName=null
    id=12
    locatorId=1
    identityHashCode=1729779847
    reified=false)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:705)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:461)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.narrow(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2288)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.access$1200(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:125)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$9.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1373)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$9.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1368)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.internal.WeakCARCacheImpl.compute(WeakCARCacheImpl.java:116)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1430)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1355)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1344)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getServiceHandles(Providers.java:354)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getCustomProviders(Providers.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.<init>(MessageBodyFactory.java:221)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1375)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:272)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:366)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:122)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2022)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:774)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getUnqualifiedService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:786)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.IterableProviderImpl.get(IterableProviderImpl.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.RequestProcessingInitializationStage.apply(RequestProcessingInitializationStage.java:97)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.RequestProcessingInitializationStage.apply(RequestProcessingInitializationStage.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages$LinkedStage.apply(Stages.java:308)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:252)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:684)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:411)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:311)
    at com.tanmay.RestClient.ClientClass.main(ClientClass.java:11)

WARNING: HK2 service reification failed for [org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.DataSourceProvider] with an exception:
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3215)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2435)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities$3.run(Utilities.java:1308)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities$3.run(Utilities.java:1304)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getAllConstructors(Utilities.java:1304)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.findProducerConstructor(Utilities.java:1247)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.DefaultClassAnalyzer.getConstructor(DefaultClassAnalyzer.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.JerseyClassAnalyzer.getConstructor(JerseyClassAnalyzer.java:144)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getConstructor(Utilities.java:178)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:129)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:180)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.internalReify(SystemDescriptor.java:740)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:694)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:461)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.narrow(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2288)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.access$1200(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:125)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$9.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1373)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$9.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1368)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.internal.WeakCARCacheImpl.compute(WeakCARCacheImpl.java:116)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1430)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1355)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1344)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getServiceHandles(Providers.java:354)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getCustomProviders(Providers.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.<init>(MessageBodyFactory.java:221)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1375)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:272)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:366)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:122)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2022)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:774)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getUnqualifiedService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:786)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.IterableProviderImpl.get(IterableProviderImpl.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.RequestProcessingInitializationStage.apply(RequestProcessingInitializationStage.java:97)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.RequestProcessingInitializationStage.apply(RequestProcessingInitializationStage.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages$LinkedStage.apply(Stages.java:308)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:252)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:684)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:411)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:311)
    at com.tanmay.RestClient.ClientClass.main(ClientClass.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataSource
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 62 more
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Errors were discovered while reifying SystemDescriptor(
    implementation=org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.DataSourceProvider
    contracts={javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter,javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader}
    scope=javax.inject.Singleton
    qualifiers={}
    descriptorType=CLASS
    descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
    metadata=
    rank=0
    loader=org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder$2@87a85e1
    proxiable=null
    proxyForSameScope=null
    analysisName=null
    id=12
    locatorId=1
    identityHashCode=1729779847
    reified=false)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:705)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:461)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.narrow(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2288)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.access$1200(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:125)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$9.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1373)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$9.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1368)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.internal.WeakCARCacheImpl.compute(WeakCARCacheImpl.java:116)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1430)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1355)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1344)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getServiceHandles(Providers.java:354)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getCustomProviders(Providers.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.<init>(MessageBodyFactory.java:221)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1375)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:272)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:366)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:122)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2022)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:774)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getUnqualifiedService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:786)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.IterableProviderImpl.get(IterableProviderImpl.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.RequestProcessingInitializationStage.apply(RequestProcessingInitializationStage.java:97)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.RequestProcessingInitializationStage.apply(RequestProcessingInitializationStage.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages$LinkedStage.apply(Stages.java:308)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:252)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:684)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:411)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:311)
    at com.tanmay.RestClient.ClientClass.main(ClientClass.java:11)
```

In this class I am calling the rest service.

```
package com.tanmay.RestClient;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
public class ClientClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        Response response = client.target("http://localhost:8080/demorest/webresources/students/student/Jamie").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();
        Student student = response.readEntity(Student.class);
        System.out.println(response.getStatus());
        System.out.println(student);
        
}
}
```

The rest service is working properly. I checked it via postman and also using java's inbuilt Http classes but I want to do it using jersey. This is my **pom.xml** file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.mytest</groupId>
 <artifactId>jax-rs-projClient</artifactId>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>jax-rs-projClient Maven Webapp</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
 <dependencies>
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
       <version>2.25.1</version>
   </dependency>
   
   
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-moxy -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
   <version>2.27</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
   <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
   
 </dependencies>
 

 <build>
   <plugins>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.5.1</version>
           <configuration>
               <source>1.8</source>
               <target>1.8</target>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

This is the response I got by using post man and Http methods of java, on hitting the same url.

```
{
    "student": {
        "age": "40",
        "city": "London",
        "email": "Lion@gmail.com",
        "id": "104",
        "marks": "60",
        "name": "Jamie",
        "sex": "male"
    }
}
```

I am a beginner in this, I am trying to problem shoot this for over a week now. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34419/991710) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java/5756989#5756989) answer. Also make sure to check that your build environment and execution environment have the same Java Version.

Comment: I checked both the posts and made sure build path and runtime classpath have the same java version and dependencies. It still gives the same error :(